# Redshift: How to List Roles?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I don't think I've every asked such a simple question :(

But how does one List Roles in Redshift ?

For groups you simply select from pg_groups.

Not so for roles, and surprisingly little documentation.

What am I missing ?

Comment: Is SVV_ROLES sufficient? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_SVV_ROLES.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [SVV_ROLES](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_SVV_ROLES.html) system view.

It does not contain a lot of information, but gives you:

- role_id   (integer)   The role ID.
- role_name     (text)  The name of the role.
- role_owner    (text)  The name of the role owner.
- external_id   (text)  The unique identifier of the role in the third-party identity provider.